# keras flow_from_directory returns 0 images

Tags: keras, image-classification

When I try to use the following snippet of code to try to predict on a batch of images, I get a message saying that no image were found:

```py
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory='test/',
        target_size=(300, 300),
        color_mode="rgb",
        shuffle = False,
        class_mode='binary',
        batch_size=1)

filenames = test_generator.filenames
```

My directory structure is as follows.
I first have a main directory named dogs_vs_cats in which I have two sub directories train and test containing the respective images and also the notebook which contains this code.

Comment: Could you post the exact ErrorMessage?

Comment: I actually solved the issue just now. I forgot to create 2 subdirectories inside the respective train and test folders and put the images in them.
Thanks anyway

Comment: The output actually was 'Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras `generator` alway looks for subfolders (representing the classes). Images insight the subfolders are associated with a class.

So when you work on `C:\images\` and you have two classes, say C1, C2, you need to create subfolders `C:\images\C1\` and `C:\images\C2\`. The directory insight the generator function should point to `C:\images\`.

See this post for the case of image prediction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991598/9524424

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

There is another option where you do not have to copy the test file into another test file:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory('.', classes=['test'])
```

This solved my problem. For more info see [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/loading-unlabeled-images-with-imagedatagenerator-flowfromdirectory-keras).

Answer (score 1):

There could be two situations when you run `ImageDataGenerator` on test set of images.

**Case #1**:  Test folder has subfolders representing the classes.
              Peter has answered this part.

**Case #2**: There are no labelled test images. In this case, you will have a single test folder which contains all the images that you want to classify.

Kyle Banks has written a tip to handle this in his blog: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/loading-unlabeled-images-with-imagedatagenerator-flowfromdirectory-keras